# Ruby: How to map a function to a hash

Tags: ruby, function, hash

I can't figure out how to assign a function call to a ruby hash.
What I want to do is to assign a function to a hash key, and later
call this function using the classic hash lookout syntax.

```
def Foo()
  puts "bar"
end

puts "Assigning"
test = { "foo" => Foo() }

puts "Executing"
test["foo"]
```

This code fails, function Foo is called after `puts "Assign"`, during hash creation, and nothing happens after `puts "Executing"`

```
def Foo()
  puts "bar"
end

puts "Assigning"
test = { "foo" => Foo }

puts "Executing"
test["foo"]
```

with this code I receive an `uninitialized constant Foo (NameError)`.

Finally with

```
def Foo()
  puts "bar"
end

puts "Assigning"
test = { "foo" => :Foo }

puts "Executing"
test["foo"]
```

I get not outputs.

Any suggestions?

Thanks to all for answres and suggestions.

What I'm going to do is to test
if a hash based approach to call function is faster than
an equivalent code based on `if` / `case` statements.

`funcs["foo"].call`

fatser than

```
if func_name == "foo" then
  Foo()
elsif ...
...
end
```

or

```
case func_name
when "foo"
  Foo()
when ...
  ...
end
```

Obviously for a big number of functions (~150) and hundreds of
calling cycles

Comment: one quick suggestion - don't define a function with title case; Ruby will expect it to be a constant rather than a function.

Answer (score 4):

you could use lambda's instead of methods. Two options here:

```
hash = {:foo => lambda { puts 'bar } }

hash[:foo].call
```

the second (more complicated) is this:

```
irb(main):001:0> class Hash
irb(main):002:1>   alias :orig_anc :'[]'
irb(main):003:1>
irb(main):004:1*   def [](key)
irb(main):005:2>     if orig_anc(key).is_a? Proc
irb(main):006:3>       orig_anc(key).call
irb(main):007:3>     else
irb(main):008:3*       orig_anc(key)
irb(main):009:3>     end
irb(main):010:2>   end
irb(main):011:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):012:0> h = {:hello => 'world', :foo => lambda { puts 'bar' }}
=> {:hello=>"world", :foo=>#<Proc:0x843224c@(irb):12 (lambda)>}
irb(main):013:0> h[:hello]
=> "world"
irb(main):014:0> h[:foo]
bar
=> nil
irb(main):015:0>
```

The second one just allows you to skip using 'call' method

Answer (score 3):

There is no easy possibility to make your function execute simply by retrieving the hash key withput overriding `Hash`'s `[]` method, as Vlad pointed out, i.e.

```
def foo
  puts "hi"
end

... # magic

test["foo"] # outputs hi
```

won't work. What you can do, though, is assign the method reference using [Object#method](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001038) and then invoke it using `call`:

```
def foo
  puts "hi"
end

test = { "foo" => method(:foo) }

test["foo"].call # => hi
```

Comment: What if the method takes arguments???

Answer (score 0):

First things first, start method names with lower case letters. Then, moving to first example,  Ruby is eager so `test = { "foo" => Foo() }` `Foo` is called.

In the second example, variables starting with an uppercase letter are considered constants, so Ruby looks for one and do not bother looking for a method. Take into account that if `foo` where a method then foo would be called as in the first example.

Third example: `test["foo"]` returns :Foo, a symbol. Nowhere in your code `Foo()` is invoked.

**Suggestions*

1.- Take a look at identifiers nomenclature in Ruby.

2.- You may took a look at `lambda`, [`Proc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Proc.html) and [`Object#method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001038)

3.- If you have some money to spare and don't mind buying a pair of books, give Programming Ruby and Metaprogramming in Ruby a chance (both can be bought in [PragProg](http://www.pragprog.com).

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the hash constructor with a block, so

```
def foo
  puts "hi"
end

test = Hash.new do |hash, key|
  send(key) if respond_to?(key)
end

test["foo"] # prints "hi", returns nil
```